# How to get editors restored when reopening a closed VS Code window?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode on my Mac (Latest version) and when I hit the "Red X" on the top left of VSCode it closes my entire workspace and open editors. I want it to just close the window out of my view but keep everything open when I re-open the app (it is still running as it still has the white dot below).. I am getting the welcome page everytime I just "close window" and re-open.

Now if I were to two click and hit Quit, then yes, I'd expect my workspace and editors to all close and get the startup menu on re-opening.

I have tried searching in the settings and cannot find anything.

[GUI Red X - VSCODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkRf7.png)
Example. When playing music on iTunes and press the "RedX" on the GUI music keeps playing and everything opens as it was when it was closed. Thatis what I am trying to acheive on VSCode. Keep my "sandbox" and open files as is when pressing it..

Answer (score 0):

To VS Code, I'm pretty sure that red x button and quit are the same thing (although it may be possible for it to treat them differently). Ie. I'm not aware of a way that you can get different behaviour for the red x button and the application quit action.

As for choosing whether the previous workspace should be reopened automatically, you can use the `window.restoreWindows` setting.

> Controls how windows are being reopened after starting for the first time. This setting has no effect when the application is already running.

The values to choose from and their descriptions at the time of this writing are:

| value | description |
| --- | --- |
| `"all"` (default value) | Reopen all windows unless a folder, workspace or file is opened (e.g. from the command line). |
| `"folders"` | Reopen all windows that had folders or workspaces opened unless a folder, workspace or file is opened (e.g. from the command line). |
| `"none"` | Never reopen a window. Unless a folder or workspace is opened (e.g. from the command line), an empty window will appear. |
| `"one"` | Reopen the last active window unless a folder, workspace or file is opened (e.g. from the command line). |
| `"preserve"` | Always reopen all windows. If a folder or workspace is opened (e.g. from the command line) it opens as a new window unless it was opened before. If files are opened they will open in one of the restored windows. |

If you want open editors to be remembered and the previous workspace to be reopened automatically when you reopen VS Code,

You may also want to set something for the `workbench.startupEditor` setting, such as:

```json
"workbench.startupEditor": "welcomePage", // or "none" or "newUntitledFile"
```

Also, loosely related is the `"workbench.editor.restoreViewState` setting, but the default value is `true`, so you only need to touch it if you don't want view state info like scroll position to be resotred on reopening closed editors.